# document ready fires too early?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, document, document-ready

It is kind of theoretical question as it can't be checked right away. The problem is about the possible reasons why the jQuery code doesn't work, however it is loaded on the page now. Also, it DOES what it has to do right after the page is loaded and I copy-paste this script code from the source of the loaded page into the console.

```
<body>
<div id="id1">...</div>
<div id="id2">some html code goes here... </div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var el = jQuery("#id1");
            var var1 = el.width();
            el.css({'margin-top':'10px','margin-bottom':'20px'});
            jQuery("#id2").css('margin-top', var1+'px');
    });
</script>
<div>and here... </div>
</body>
```

P.S. The jQuery library is loaded. There are no errors in the Chrome console. The script is in the body tag.

P.P.S. Can it be because of `#id1` (contains ) is loaded from another site so document ready fired earlier? Is that exactly the reason?
Any other possible reasons?

Unfortunately, it is hard to check it right away as the access to that page is limited and takes several steps to update by other persons that can't be accessible right away.
However, the possible solution is needed right away.

**Added id1 and id2 into the html code.**

Comment: try `$(window).load()`

Comment: How are the elements with the id `#id1` and `#id2` loaded into the page?

Comment: You have to wait until #id1 and #id2 is in the page and then execute you script. Dom-ready only cares about the current page and not about additionally loaded html.

Comment: Short answer: no, it doesn't. Long answer: What are the `#id1` and `#id2` elements? Where's the rest of the script (I assume there's more as this has syntax errors in it)

Comment: I've added id1 and id2 into the html code.
@blgt - Could you please tell me about the syntax errors? Thank you.

Comment: `.ready(` is missing its closing bracket `);`. ALSO: Consider that if you're loading the `div`'s content remotely, calling `.width()` on it could return `0` if its content hasn't loaded yet. The function in `.ready()` runs as soon as the html renders, it doesn't wait for remote content.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the typo. Yes, I missed ); here.

Answer (score 0):

> use ***window.onload*** is most often used within the  element to
>   execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {

    var el = jQuery("#id1");
            var var1 = el.width();
            el.css({'margin-top':'10px','margin-bottom':'20px'});
            jQuery("#id2").css('margin-top', var1+'px');

});
```